# How to set the max queue time in Kafka 0.9 producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How to setup the max queue time in Kafka v0.9?

My understanding is that the Kafka producer will try to buffer the messages in a queue to a certain size and then send the messages in the queue as batch to broker. However in Kafka v0.8, the configuration of "queue.buffering.max.ms" will send the messages in the queue when it reaches the time limit, even if they are smaller than the buffer size.

> The batching can be configured to accumulate no more than a fixed number of messages and to wait no longer than some fixed latency bound (say 64k or 10 ms).

from Kafka 0.9 document:
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design_asyncsend. (This section is the same as Kafka 0.8.2)

But I didn't find the configuration of "queue.buffering.max.ms" or equivalent in the v0.9 producer configuration section http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs

Is there still a way to configure this in Kafka v0.9 or I have to call `KafkaProducer.close()` or `KafkaProducer.flush()` to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that configuration use `batch.size` and `linger.ms`

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood `linger.ms` before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `batch.size` and `queue.time`, NOT `linger.ms` as stated in the accepted answer.

`linger.ms` is the delay before sending out a batch of requests, but is defaulted to zero and not the max time before sending out a batch.

See: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation  for more details.